# Limitations of Apache POI and Microsoft Open XML SDK in reading and writting presenations

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

My scenario is that i need to create presentations out of slides from various presentations. In a typical case, I create a new presentation and keep importing slides content to it using XMLSlideShow.createSlide().importContent. This method works fine in simple slides, but if i have slides  like the one below, I get empty slides.

[image]

I tested merging around 8 presentation files with around 450 slides. 100 of 450 slides were empty (25%). Therefore, it is a serious problem for our application.

As a result, I am evaluating alternatives to Apache POI, we can switch to a different platform if it is open source and produces high quality presentations.

One potential alternative is Microsoft Open XML SDK. However, before switching, it will be good to know the limitations of Open XML SDK as compared to POI. Any thoughts on that? I am opened to other open source projects if they fulfill my needs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try working out the difference between slides that worked and slides that didn't? Did PowerPoint give any warnings when opening problematic slides? Can Apache POI read the contents back from problematic slides?

Comment: Yes, I can extract texts from problematic slides and export them into png. However, my trouble is importing these slides into a new presentation using XMLSlideShow.createSlide().importContent(). See  [my post in poi forums](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/How-to-import-complex-shaps-Using-POI-XMLSlideShow-td5717798.html)

Comment: Our Docx4j Enterprise Edition can merge presentations for you, but its a commercial add on for docx4j/pptx4j (which is ASLv2 open source ).